# Can't connect to localhost in React Native WebView

Tags: react-native

I started up a simple http server ([from here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Web_server#Python)):

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    yield b"<h1>Goodbye, World!</h1>"

server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8080, app)
server.serve_forever()
```

Ran it using:

```
python3 simple_serve.py
```

Redirecting to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` displays "Goodbye, World!".

I then created a new React Native Project and changed `index.android.js` to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  WebView,
} from 'react-native';

export default class WebTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source= {{ uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" }}
      />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('WebTest', () => WebTest);
```

"Goodbye, World!" doesn't show up, and I get a warning that says:

> Encountered an error loading page
>   `{"canGoForward"false,"code":-6,"canGoBack":false,"description":"net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED","loading":false,"title":"","url":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/","target":5}`

For reference, changing `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` to `https://www.google.com` works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use that IP **`10.0.2.2`**  instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: 10.0.3.2 ( In case of genymotion ) and 10.0.2.2 ( In case of emulator ), both connects to local development machine.

Answer (score 20):

I had success doing :

```
adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

My webview:

```
<WebView source={{uri: 'http://localhost:3000'}} ...
```

Comment: This works for me, but what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a mac and i found the proper ip address in the network settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

use it like that http://10.0.2.2://your port num this will work definetly

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44702725/666583), which has already been accepted by the asker, and is not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to localhost by finding my computer's IP Address. Open cmd prompt and type this for mac:

```
ifconfig | grep inet
```

Windows:

```
ipconfig/ALL
```

mine was listed between inet & netmask exhttp://194.178.1.2:4242/ and as Webview uri worked fine

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of failure when attempting to send requests to your own WiFi IP address, depending on the network configuration.
If other solutions in this question have been unsuccessful, you can consider trying the approach I propose.

By utilizing tools like `ngrok`, you can expose your localhost server to an external IP address and subsequently send requests to that IP from your React Native application.